# Paraview python command to save picture of defined size

Tags: python, paraview

In paraview, I can save a picture from the python terminal like:

```
WriteImage('pic.png')
```

… but does anyone know how to save the figure with a defined size (like 1600 x 1000 pixels)?

I am using ParaView 4.1.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The size of the picture is based on the size of the view, so you just need to change the size of the view as follows:

```
view = GetRenderView()
view.ViewSize = [1600,1000]
WriteImage('pic.png')
```